# Please identify this creature found on the beach

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

Found on beach in Atlantic Canada in November.

"Sack" is approx. 2" (approx. 5cm) in length.

[image]

Comment: any opening, or shell? looks like a n innkeeper worm.

Comment: Just a guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sipuncula

Answer (score 2):

I've actually seen these before during an invertebrate zoology class in Maine! It's a rat-tailed sea cucumber, Caudina arenata. Though I don't have the taxonomic guide book anymore, I found [this blog post](https://cosresearch.wordpress.com/2018/03/07/mysterious-marine-creatures-washed-up-by-storm/) that cites an old guide with more info about them.